# table of uniquely named objects

Tags: c++, hashmap, c++14

I would like to tabulate

```
struct object {
    std::string unique_name;
    some_type more_data;
    other_type member_functions() const; // many such member functions
};
```

using the `unique_name` as index. Unfortunately, I cannot use

```
using object_table = std::unordered_set<object>;
```

since there is no way to search for an object given a name, as `object_table::find()` only allows for search keys of type `object`:

```
class objects {
    object_table _table;
  public:
    object const&operator[](std::string const&name) const
    {
        // cannot be implemented using object_table::find()
    }
};
```

So what can I do?

My awkward solution so far was

```
using object_table = std::unordered_map<std::string, some_type>;

struct object : object_table::value_type
{
    std::string const&name() const { return first; }
    other_type member_functions() const;
  private:
    using object_table::value_type::first;
    using object_table::value_type::second;
};

class objects {
    object_table _table;
  public:
    object const&operator[](std::string const&name) const
    {
        auto it = _table.find(name);
        if(it == _table.end())
            throw runtime_error("cannot find object '"+name+'\'');
        return *static_cast<const object*>(std::addressof(*it));  // is cast legal?
    } 
};
```

This works at the price for patching `object` together in an cumbersome way from a `std::pair<std::string, some_type>`.

Comment: Can you add member functions to `struct object`?

Comment: If you are willing to switch to a `std::set` you can use `std::set::find` with just a `std::string`.

Comment: @NathanOliver I know, but I rather want to keep the hashtable O(n) performance for insertion and lookup.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat The design of `object` is in my hands.

Comment: @Walter Maybe, you clarify what exactly your code is supposed to do and ask at [SE Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I want to look up objects by their unique name. Ideally, the objects should be of the form indicated in the first code snippet. What *exactly* is missing/unclear?

Comment: Actually, due to poor cache locality of unordered_set buckets, std::map tends to be faster than unordered set for small sets. Break even is somewhere between 1,000 and 10,000 elements, for gcc and clang

Answer (score 3):

Since your names are unique per object you can just use the hash of `unique_name` as the hash for your object.  Using

```
namespace std
{
    template<> struct hash<object>
    {
        typedef object argument_type;
        typedef std::size_t result_type;
        result_type operator()(argument_type const& o) const noexcept
        {
            return std::hash<std::string>{}(o.unique_name);
        }
    };
}

bool operator ==(const object& lhs, const object& rhs)
{
    return lhs.unique_name == rhs.unique_name;
}
```

The lets you write the lookup code like

```
using object_table = std::unordered_set<object>;

class objects 
{
    object_table _table;
  public:
    object const&operator[](std::string const&name) const
    {
        if (auto it = object_table.find(object{name}); it != object_table.end())
            return *it
        else
            throw();
    }
};
```

This does require that `object` be constuctable from a single`std::string` and that it is used to initialize `unique_name`.

Comment: I think you need to provide overload for `operator==` for the `object` as well

Comment: @KillzoneKid Good call.  I forgot it still used an equality check.

Comment: Yes, I have considered this option too. I rejected it because it requires to create an `object` just for the sake of lookup, even though only the name is technically needed.